# WP Theme page displays in IE but not in Firefox

Tags: wordpress-theming

Hi
I have a WPTheme problem with a page not displaying in Firefox and I have tried to fix this but so far I cannot see why & have had no success in fixing it!
(strangely it displays as it should in Internet Explorer browser)

The page/site can be seen at [my wponlinethemetest site](http://onlinewpthemetest.richard-dickinson.com/)

I am grateful for help to fix this & look forward to helpful replies. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Spudley for your reply.
I did run the code through the validator & saw it give out around 200 errors. 
Most of these I presume are from WordPress php/template tag code!
Is that possible?
The original index.html file passed validation.

I later found there wasa problem with a call to comments/commentblock enclosed in divs within my WP loop.
When I changed this the page layout resorted to normality! Problem solved.
Thanks again for your helpful reply

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing to do is run your code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). This will show you the errors in your HTML; there are quite a few, so I won't go through them here, but I believe once you've tidied them up, the page should render better in all browsers.

Hope that helps.